# Pandas assignment efficiency

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas dataframe where I will be adding a new column (SUGGESTED).
Once new column is added, I'm using the following pattern to update it with a new value based on the value of QUERY column. Example:

```
QUERY = 'query'
SUGGESTED = 'suggested'
df[SUGGESTED] = numpy.nan
s_query = 'de'
new_value = 'delaware'
df.loc[(df[QUERY] == s_query), [SUGGESTED]] = new_value
```

Example:

```
query suggested
al      alabama
ca      california
de      NaN
```

After:

```
query suggested
    al      alabama
    ca      california
    de      delaware
```

It seems to work so far, not sure if there is a more efficient way to do it in Pandas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can first omit `df[SUGGESTED] = numpy.nan` in `loc` and `np.where` solution, because it add new column:

```
QUERY = 'query'
SUGGESTED = 'suggested'
s_query = 'de'
new_value = 'delaware'

#if need update existing column
df[SUGGESTED] = df[SUGGESTED].mask(df[QUERY] == s_query, new_value)
print (df)
  query   suggested
0    al     alabama
1    ca  california
2    de    delaware
```

Solution with `loc` can be simplify remove `()` if only one condition and remove `[]` if only one column:

```
#for updating existing column 
df.loc[df[QUERY] == s_query, SUGGESTED] = new_value
print (df)
  query   suggested
0    al     alabama
1    ca  california
2    de    delaware

#same for creating new column
df.loc[df[QUERY] == s_query, SUGGESTED] = new_value
print (df)
  query suggested
0    al       NaN
1    ca       NaN
2    de  delaware
```

If need replace by `NaN` where no match:

```
#same for creating and updating existing column
df[SUGGESTED] = np.where(df[QUERY] == s_query, new_value, np.nan)
print (df)
  query suggested
0    al       nan
1    ca       nan
2    de  delaware
```

Comment: In terms of np.where example is there an option to: match row if query is found, update the column with new_value, but don't do anything if there is no match? As you point out current example overwrite other rows with np.nan.

Comment: I think you need `df[SUGGESTED] = df[SUGGESTED].mask(df[QUERY] == s_query, new_value)` - see [`mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.mask.html)